# Highlight group for signature help

Tags: highlight, plugin-you-complete-me, popup-menu

I'm using Vim (v. 8.2) with [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe) as a code completion engine. I welcome the addition of signature help, but I'm not happy with the default colors:

[image: default signature help for desert colorscheme]

Does anyone know **what highlight group is related to signature help** so that I can **tweak its appearance**?

This should be tweak-able, since using a different color scheme (gruvbox in my case) and switching back to my default (desert) gives a modified appearance:

[image]

At the end, I'd like to try making the current argument have no background coloring and be displayed in bold instead. The `Pmenu` (and `PmenuSel` etc) group is irrelevant to the signature help (it does control the appearance of the autocompletion menu but doesn't help much with signature help)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Thanks for writing a detailed question.

Comment: Try `:sign list` to see the list of signs, and look for `texthl` in the output (based on `:help sign`; untested). I'm not sure you can modify already-placed signs, and the highlight group is defined when they are placed. But you can modify said group, if you find out what it is. EDIT: perhaps you really meant function signatures, in which case ignore what I said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlight group used to style the current argument is called `YCMInverse`, since its default is to reverse foreground and background colors.

Its default is defined [here](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/blob/57f2191a0b106acf2d7f7673fc023176e5d4b73e/autoload/youcompleteme.vim#L172) as:

```
hi default YCMInverse term=reverse cterm=reverse gui=reverse
```

Since it's defined using [`hi default`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahighlight-default), you can override it by setting your own from your vimrc.

For example, to highlight it in bold, instead of reverse, you can add the following line to your vimrc:

```
hi YCMInverse term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
```

Unfortunately, the `YCMInverse` group doesn't really seem to be documented in YouCompleteMe's help file. (Other highlight groups are documented there, but not this particular one.)

Comment: What about the background (`ctermbg`) for the signature help?