# Signature popup has unreadable colors in YCM for Rust

Tags: highlight, plugin-you-complete-me, popup-menu

I'm using Vim 8.2 with rust highlighter and YCM plugin for auto-completion and signature help.

Everything works except method signature:

[image]

It has same color for both color text and bg in parts like `self` in `(&mut self, other ...`.

I have already seen [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/25195/highlight-group-for-signature-help) but was not helpful. Can anyone help?

Comment: @BLayer Highlights only appear in Insert mode, once I go to Normal mode to run any command, it disappears. +tried colorscheme route, no luck.

Comment: @BLayer it may not be clear, but OP is talking about highlighting inside a popup. Those aren't trivial to extract information from…

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks. I totally missed that. D'oh!

Comment: Depending on what is used, changing the highlight for Popup (or PopupMenu or Sel or whatever it is) might help. You could also take a look at the plugin to see if you can figure out how it does the highlights. (That looks like a fairly default vim colorscheme, and the completion menu does have an ugly pink color in the default…)

Comment: FYI, by default popups use PMenu/PMenuSel for text coloring unless Popup/PopupSelected are defined in which case those are used. (If memory serves me correctly.) The screenshot doesn't appear to be showing the godawful default "magenta", though (unless the hue settings are way out of whack.) :)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble A gift:  `if execute("hi Pmenu") =~? 'guibg=\a*magenta' | hi Pmenu guibg=black | endif` (Works well in a `Colorscheme` autocmd.)  :D

Comment: @BLayer mentioning `PMenu` was very useful because there are way too many highlight colors, and I didn't know which one to change. Changing `guibg` didn't help and after search I realized I should change `ctermbg` which fixed the issue!

Comment: Glad you found a solution. FYI `guibg` is only relevant in GUI Vim OR terminal Vim when 24-bit color is configured (`:h 'termguicolors'`)

Answer (score 1):

On my setup, `Pmenu` is responsible for the popup (see BLayer's [comment](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/33014/signature-popup-has-unreadable-colors-in-ycm-for-rust#comment60174_33014)) so:

```
:hi Pmenu ctermbg=darkgray
```

or add it to your vimrc, below all other styling rules:

```
highlight Pmenu ctermbg=darkgray
```